# IntelliJ IDEA: prevent redeploy for any little change

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA and developing web application in Java.
Is there any way that I debug my app without redeploy for any little change? the redeploy thing makes the working very slow and annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Update action](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/updating-a-running-java-ee-application.html) in IntelliJ IDEA is configurable, in case of exploded web application you can set what to do: update resources, update classes and resources, redeploy, restart the server. In most cases it's enough to update classes and resources. Update can be performed automatically on frame deactivation (when you switch from IDEA to the browser).

Comment: @CrazyCoder, could you advise me if I can configure manually what files are to be considered as "resources" for IDEA? I cannot update LESS files without redeploying :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245872/intellij-idea-jboss-doesnt-update-less-files-on-runtime-compilation

Comment: Files residing is source directory are considered resources. In a Maven project it's defined by your pom.xml configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what are you redeploying, JSP or raw Java class? If you change a Java class then IDEA will not compile it and redeploy by itself. If you change a JSP (pr JSF...) you can click package file (Ctrl+Shift+F9) from right mouse click menu.

If you use Netbeans, Netbeans does this for you. I am also fan of IDEA but I liked Netbeans due to this feature.