# Intellij IDEA + JBoss doesn't update LESS files on runtime compilation

Tags: java, jboss, intellij-idea, runtime, less

unfortunately googling didn't help :(
I have deployed a simple project on JBoss5.x integrated in my Intellij IDEA.
I use some mvc frameworks with JSP pages. 
So I run my project, works with it and when I edit any JSP I can just click "Run" >> "Update JBoss" >> "Update resources" and all my changes to JSPs will be applied without redeploying the server. 
But this doesn't work with LESS files (LESS is for dynamic css). I cannot figured out why? Any hints?

PS: less file is mentioned on JSP correctly, so it is applied normally, but changes to it cannot be applied without redeploying.

Comment: What happens when you try to deploy those LESS files? Does it seem that they have been uploaded or do you get some sort of an error?

Comment: @Dropout, no errors at all, so at first I thought I just need to clear browser's cache to see my changes being applied but it didn't help :( If I redeploy my project totally then changes are applied, but I was wondering why IDEA "Update resources" doesn't affect LESS files changes.

Comment: Just a wild guess but have you checked the owner of those files on the targeted system? I had a similar problem and my stuff couldn't get deployed because the user under which I was trying to do so didn't have neccessary rights..

Comment: @Dropout hmm..checked but no constraints on their using..besides those LESS files are mine...

Comment: yeah but does the user under which you run the JBOSS server have the rights to use them? or is it the same user?

Comment: @Dropout sorry man, I'm still a newbie :( if you mean "user" related to user in my operation system, then - yes. It's me who created those LESS files, then ran JBOSS integrated into IDEA.

Comment: Can you try deploying them directly via SCP/WinSCP, please (not using integrated JBOSS deployment in idea)? That could tell us if the problem is in your IDE or on the server side. THanks

Comment: thx man, I've mentioned, that they are deployed normally. The problem is that "Update resources" feauture in IDEA doesn't affect them like JSPs for example...So I have to redeploy every time I change LESS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deploying the files directly, not through IDEA, to see if it's a problem of your IDE configuration or a server-side issue.

If it's a server-side problem (the files don't get deployed even with the direct deploy), then try checking stuff like permissions on files, if the deployer works and if it's listening for new files, etc.. Also some files cannot be "hot-deployed" without actual redeploying of the whole module of your application.

If it's a problem with your IDE then try checking your configuration. Here are some links which should help you get started:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/training/demos/JBoss_server.html

https://community.jboss.org/thread/202446?start=0&tstart=0

[How does Intellij deploy to JBoss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492520/how-does-intellij-deploy-to-jboss)

If you have any further questions, please ask in the comments. Cheers!

Edit: I am not an expert on hot deployment, nor can I specify exactly which files can or cannot be hot-deployed, but AFAIK you can hot-deploy changes to your classes which do not change the structure of your class. This most of the time means that you can change the body of a method and hotdeploy it without any problems, however if you rename it or add new methods completely you won't be able to hot-swap them. Another thing is file discovery - files which are discovered during the startup phase of the server cannot be hotdeployed without a restart or some other way which tells the server to reload them. This might be your case.. I hope that someone will specify these hot-deploying limits better.

Comment: thx again. I like your words "Also some files cannot be "hot-deployed" without actual redeploying". This is the matter - I want to know how to understand what files can be hot-deployed in IDEA when I choose "Update resources"...

Comment: I've edited some stuff in. I'm hoping for some deployment guru also - this topic interests me. Don't mark it as answered yet, please ;)